# c++11 lambda: difference between transform and for_each

Tags: c++11, lambda

I'm trying to convert every character in a string to lower case. And both transform and foreach can do this in one line:

```
// use transform
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
// use for_each
for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char &c){c = std::tolower(c);});
```

So, what's the difference? Which one is better in the efficiency of time and space?

Comment: std::transform does not do what for_each does, also "transofrm" and "lambda" are un-related things, it's like asking what's the difference between a pointer and an argument..

Comment: I doubt whether `for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char &c){std::tolower(c);});` really works. Should probably be `for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char &c){c = std::tolower(c);});`.

Comment: @cpplearner Yes, you are right. I miswrote this one. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHaim It's my bad. I've changed the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, `transform` vs `for_each`? Because you can also use lambdas as the functions for `transform`.

In this case, there's no real difference between `transform` and `for_each`. `for_each` is the more general algorithm, I'd use transform in this case because otherwise you're just re-implementing transform using for_each, which is less clear IMHO, although clarity is somewhat subjective so your mileage may vary.

In terms of efficiency, there wouldn't be a difference in this case. In the future, if you're interested in that kind of thing, it's probably easier to just measure it.

Comment: True, but I'm not sure how that's relevant for this case

Answer (score 2):

The two algorithms, **for_each** and **transform** seem very similar in functioning, as both perform an operation to every element of the sequence.

However, there are some conceptual differences between them:

1. **for_each** discards the operation's return value, while **transform** copies the return value to an element in the output range.
2. **for_each** is a **non-modifying** algorithm; **transform** is a **mutating** algorithm. This means that **for_each** does not implicitly modify a sequence. Non modifying algorithms(like count, find) do not assign to any sequence elements. However, the actual purpose of **for_each** lies in the effects that the function object that is supplied to **for_each** produces when it is invoked for each element in the input sequence. **transform**, being a modifying/mutating algorithm produces effects by modifying the elements of given sequence.
3. This difference can be comprehended from 2nd difference: **for_each** allows side-effects produced(if any) by function object, while **transform** must not have a function object that produces side-effect(s). It is because **transform** in itself is able to produce a side-effect(s). In fact, in case of using **for_each**, invocation of a function object that is free from side-effects is pointless.

[Refer to the following, for greater insights on **for_each** vs **transform**](https://www.drdobbs.com/effective-standard-c-library-foreach-vs/184403769)